# Changing the content of html page based on language selected using json

Tags: html, angularjs, json

In my app the user is requested to select a language, based on which the all the content in the app are changed to that specific language. I use a json array to get the user information, so I have stored it as,

```
  {"uniqueId":1238902,
         {
    "english":{
        "username":"Sherif",
        "phone" :(234)567-0988
    },
    "arabic":{
        "name":"شريف",
         "phone": (234)567-0988}}
```

But Im able to display only one language in my html,

```
{{"User Name" |translate}}:
    <input type="text" ng-model="editingInfo[0].arabic.name">
    <br>
    {{"Phone"translate}}:
    <input type="number" ng-model="editingInfo[0].arabic.phone">
    <br>
    <button ng-click="save()">
```

controller:

```
//selecting specific user to edit
$scope.editing=function(key){
$scope.editingInfo=[];
for (var i=0; i<$scope.userInfo.length;i++)
{
if($scope.userInfo[i].uniqueId == key.uniqueId){
$scope.editingInfo.push($scope.userInfo[i]);
};
};
```

So, How will I make use of the both the language in same html page. What is the mistake I'm making while calling the data in html.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution conception

Best solution for this case is to have service which will manage all language concerns in our app. Such language service should know what language is currently set on page and take text from proper language array.

Some example getter in such service should look like:

```
this.getText = function(textSymbol){
 return langTexts[currentChosenLanguageSymbol][textSymbol];
}
```

Example usage:

```
someLangService.getText("name");
```

So developer using this service needs to know only word symbol, service should provide proper word.

---

### Solution example

I created working service with working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.service("lang", function(){

  //possible to choose langs
  var langs=[
    {label:"English", symbol:"english", id:1},
    {label:"Arabic", symbol:"arabic", id:2}
  ];
  
  
  //object contains lang texts used in app
  var texts={
    "english":{
        "name":"Sherif",
        "phone" :"(234)567-0988"
    },
    "arabic":{
        "name":"شريف",
        "phone": "(234)567-0988"
    }
    };
  
  
  this.getLangueges = function(){
    return langs;    
  };
  
  this.setLanguage = function(lang){
    this.language=lang;
  };
  
  this.getLanguage = function(){
    return this.language;  
  };
  
  this.getText = function(symbol){
    return texts[this.language.symbol][symbol];
  };
  
  //set default as english
  this.setLanguage(langs[0]);
  
});

app.controller('controller', function(lang, $scope){
  
  //set service into view
  $scope.lang = lang;
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

  <select ng-options="lang as lang.label for lang in lang.getLangueges() track by lang.id" ng-model="lang.language" ></select>
  
  <h3>{{lang.getText("name")}}</h3>
</div>
```

**One note more** - I have changed little bit format of storing language texts, structure pasted in question had different keys in different languages, and we need the same keys there with different values.

Thanks this service we no need to use arrays directly but it gives abstraction level for this, using it We can just provide text symbol and service will get proper text with proper currently chosen language.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Please provide proper JSON format it's not correct.